# Huge elements on secondary monitor with lower resolution

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, intel-graphics, hdmi, display-resolution

Ubuntu 16.04 installed on ASUS UX305 ultrabook with QHD resolution (3200x1800) of built-in display.

Connecting secondary monitor Dell 24" with 1920x1200 resolution over HDMI I am getting **huge control elements** on it.

Scaling in "All settings-Displays" doesn't help.

**Note:** Built-in is scaled to 2 as it's the only way to make it readable and convenient look.

How to get external monitor scaled independently from main built-in?

Comment: Same problem here. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the only **relatively easy** way to get independent scaling between monitor and built-in display is to use the [Wayland](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/) windows system (instead of the current Xorg).

This is available in Ubuntu 18.04, although [Xorg window system is the default](https://blog.ubuntu.com/2018/01/26/bionic-beaver-18-04-lts-to-use-xorg-by-default), you can switch at the login screen

Then in your 'Display Settings' you can set 200% for the built-in display and 100% for the monitor.

But there are still major issues. I have created a [separate question with the issues I found when using Wayland](https://askubuntu.com/q/1093107/8989). Currently only the terminal windows and file explorer windows handle the separate scaling properly. All other applications still use the scaling of the built-in display when on the monitor. This makes for a really ugly monitor as you have some windows scaled to 100% and others to 200%.

[image]