# HiDPI scaling with two screens different resolutions in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, unity, display-resolution, scaling

I have a Dell XPS 9360 on which I have just installed Ubuntu 16.04.

It has a QHD+ screen (3200 x 1800) and I'm connecting a second FHD monitor (1920 x 1080).  It is connected via USB-C and a 4K -> HDMI adaptor + cable.

I am using "Displays" to set my resolution and to set "Scale for menu and title bars".

I would like to have both screens set to max resolution with the QHD+ screen scaling set to 2 and the FHD screen on 1 (default).

I have not found any method of achieving this goal and I'm currently restricted to FHD on both screens.

Does anyone know if it's possible to set different scaling for each monitor based upon the resolution?

If this is not possible, would it then be possible to write a script that will alter the resolution and scaling to the same values for both monitors when I connect / disconnect the monitor?

Comment: Note:  I made a mistake, I can scale differently for each screen but it doesn't effect font scaling, only "menu and title bars".

Comment: Ye, so did this fix the issue

Comment: If you're staying on Ubuntu 16 try Soren A's comment for `xrandr` if you've moved to Ubuntu 18 then this question has multiple answers: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029436/enable-fractional-scaling-for-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 0):

I've [answered this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1096815/8989) on a question that is effectively the same as this earlier question about huge scaling on a monitor

You need to use the Wayland windows system which allows for independent scaling of the in-built display and the monitor.

Wayland is available in Ubuntu 17+. You can switch to Wayland at the login screen and then adjust the scaling in the 'Screen Display' settings.

I've also asked a separate question about [issues with Wayland](https://askubuntu.com/q/1093107/8989).

Comment: With xorg system you can use `xrandr` to scale each monitor, like this `xrandr --output HDMI-1 --scale 1.25x1.25` and then similar for other monitor. Use `xrandr` without arguments to show available monitors and names (depending on HW it might not be HDMI-1 and so for you).

Comment: @SorenA I was trying to keep my answer as non-technical as possible, but I think yours is a valid separate answer.

Comment: Actually my answer is done better elsewhere: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029436/enable-fractional-scaling-for-ubuntu-18-04